# How to properly install ClassPrivateProperties and ClassPrivateMethods plugins?

Tags: npm, babeljs, parceljs

Hei,

I updated my npm packages, including parcel, and after the update I could not run my application anymore and keep getting the following error:

```
     Build failed.
@parcel/transformer-js: This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): 'classPrivateProperties, classPrivateMethods' (3:2)
```

My package.json looks like below:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  },
  "author": "Klei Rama",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.13.0",
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "parcel": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fractional": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

I keep trying to delete node_modules, clear the cache, and delete package.json and then reinstall again but it does not work. I tried to use experimantal versions of parcel such as **2.0.0-beta.1** and **2.0.0-beta.2**, but none of these version does not seem to work with experimental phase of babel plugins (class-properties and private-methods) (7.13.0). I was wondering if there is any certain version of babel plugins which can work either with parcel **2.0.0-beta.1** or **2.0.0-beta.2**?

Answer (score 0):

Hei you, install babel and the following plugins:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods"
  ]
}
```

Of course, also, to file .babelrc.